# How to convert a string like "0.496,0.424,0.141" to numeric?

Tags: r, numeric

I have a column of dataframe which is like "0.496,0.424,0.141". Now I would like to convert each of them to numeric and calculate the mean value. Could anyone tell me how can I do that? Thank you in advance.

```
string1 <- "0.496,0.424,0.141"
#I have try 
mean(as.numeric(string1))
#but it didnot work
```

Comment: split string (`strsplit`): `lapply(strsplit("0.496,0.424,0.141", ","), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `read.csv` and then use `rowMeans` to get mean of every row.

```
rowMeans(read.csv(text = string1, header = FALSE))
#[1] 0.3536667
```

The same would work with `read.table` as well

```
rowMeans(read.table(text = string1, sep = ","))
```

Comment: This is smart :-)

Comment: Beautiful solution! Would have never thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more verbose than @RonakShah's solution, but maybe more understandable for beginners:

```
mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(string1, split = ","))))
[1] 0.3536667
```

#### Explanation

`strsplit()` - split the string into a list at each comma, then
`unlist()` - turn the list into a vector, then
`as.numeric()` - convert each value of the vector into numeric (= float) type, then
`mean()` - calculate the mean of the resulting vector